# CollectionDataContractAttribute for list with no group element

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer

My problem is that I would like to use the CollectionDataControlAttribute to deserialise a collection which does not have a group element. The xml looks something like this:

```
<RootElement>
    <SomeProperty />
    <ListElementEntry />
    <ListElementEntry />
    <ListElementEntry />
    <ListElementEntry />
</RootElement>
```

Where ListElementEntry appears zero or more times.

Help Appreciated

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use DataContractSerializer, (I don't know what CollectionDataControlAttribute is). XmlSerializer can easily achieve this, if that is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be `DataContractSerializer`? You can elect to use `XmlSerializer` for WCF, and then you can use:

```
[XmlRoot("RootElement"), XmlType("RootElement")]
public class Foo {
    public string SomeProperty {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("ListElementEntry")]
    public List<Bar> Bars {get {return bars;}}
    private readonly List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();
}
```

Ultimately, `DataContractSerializer` is simply *not designed* to give you the same level of xml control - which is why it doesn't support even attributes. If you need specific xml, `XmlSerializer` is usually a better choice.

Comment: Thats exactly what I went for in the end. Thanks for the help.